# Shiny server : Error config plotly

Tags: r, shiny-server, plotly

I successfully ran a Shiny Project on my computer on RStudio browser or with Chrome browser and there was no error message whatsoever but when I try to deploy it on a Shiny server I get the following error:

[image]

I am using several libraries including plotly.
I cannot really post more than this because this project is quite large but do you think you could at least decypher where this error comes from ? Some problem with plotly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work at Plotly.

Indeed, you need to specify the `base_url` parameter! :)
This is documented in our tutorial: http://moderndata.plot.ly/dashboards-in-r-with-shiny-plotly/ which includes the [source code](https://github.com/cldougl/plotly-shiny/blob/master/Examples/Movies/global.R#L6).

Answer (score 0):

I changed this :
`py <- plotly(username="rAPI", key="yu680v5eii")`
by
`py <- plotly(username="rAPI", key="yu680v5eii", base_url="https://plot.ly")`
and it works fine !